Examples of problems in statistics accessible only using information geometry
I am just curious if there are some examples of problems in statistics that are indeed accessible using information geometry while proofs completely avoiding geometry are unknown. In other words, problems solved by considering the statistical model $\mathcal{P}$ in the problem as a statistical manifold and then using results in differential geometry while proofs not really using the manifold structure is yet to be discovered.
I have posted this question first on Cross-Validated, and then on Mathematics StackExchange, but surprisingly was migrated to Cross-Validated. Both questions receive no comments or answers.

Update :
As the comment points out, there might not exist such a clear/compelling concrete example. So let me weaken the requirements to answer this post. Give any concrete example of problem in statistics such that the information geometry plays a major role in one of its solution(s). (the requirement that the problem is not known to be solved in another way is removed).

I'd say it's not so surprising, maybe there is no such clear and compelling example in the literature.

Thank you for your response. I have updated the question.

Have you read this Wikipedia article and references there, including to books and the journal Information Geometry?

This is a great question, and it's a fair criticism of IG that relatively few such results exist. For most statistical problems, it's probably most effective to attack them directly using statistical methods. As a result, I suspect the problems where IG offers a significant practical benefit tend to be a bit more eclectic. However, here are two examples which might be what you are looking for:

Natural Gradients
Stochastic Portfolio Theory

Natural Gradients are one of the most direct applications of IG, and a good demonstration for its use case. Suppose you're optimizing a loss function over a complex parametrized model $f( \mathbf{x} ~|~ \mathbf{\theta})$ using gradient descent. Typically, you would perform this optimization in the ambient Euclidean geometry of the parameter space $\mathbf{\theta}$. I'm not sure if he was the first to suggest it, but Amari [1] proposed that it’s more effective to treat the model as a statistical manifold and use the Fisher-Rao metric to define an inner product for gradient descent. In practical terms, this means pre-multiplying the gradient vector by the inverse of the Fisher information matrix. This adjustment removes the dependence of gradient descent on the specific parametrization of the model and improves performance by accounting for how much small changes in each parameter changes affect the shape of the distribution (see, for example this blog post). In practice, inverting large matrices is very computationally expensive, so I don’t think machine learning algorithms actually use natural gradients exactly but I believe some incorporate ideas to approximate them.
A more recent example lies in the intersection of IG and stochastic portfolio theory, a branch of mathematical finance that uses stochastic analysis to study market behavior and construct functionally generated investment strategies. In this context, there's a concept known as a pseudo-arbitrage—a type of investment portfolio that satisfies specific conditions relative to the market portfolio.$^\dagger$
Starting around 2014, Pal and Wong wrote a number of papers (see,
e.g., [2]) which show that pseudo-arbitrages can be systematically
constructed using information geometry and optimal transport.
Specifically, a collection of market weights can be interpreted as an element of the probability simplex, and they used the log-partition function of the associated multinomial distribution to construct a “logarithmic divergence” between market states.
Using this divergence as a cost function, they furthermore showed that the
Monge solutions to optimal transport are precisely the same as pseudo-arbitrage mappings.$^{\dagger \dagger}$ Information geometry plays a crucial role here because the cost function uses the exponential family structure of multinomial distributions in a crucial way. Additionally, properties of pseudo-arbitrages, such as their regularity theory, rely on the curvature of the associated information geometric structures.
[1]: Amari, Shin-Ichi, Natural Gradient Works Efficiently in Learning, Neural Computation
10, Issue 2, 251-276 (1998). 
[2]: Pal, Soumik; Wong, Ting-Kam Leonard, Exponentially concave functions and a new information geometry, Ann. Probab. 46, No. 2, 1070-1113 (2018). ZBL1390.60064.
$^\dagger$ More precisely, a pseudo-arbitrage is a portfolio strategy whose losses, compared to the buy-and-hold approach, are bounded so long as the market weights remain within a compact set. Additionally, there exists a sequence of market weights for which the return, relative to the market, grows without bound. Intuitively, these strategies generalize the idea of rebalancing a portfolio of equities (i.e., maintaining a constant allocation). Under the conditions of market diversity and sufficient volatility, these portfolios will outperform the market portfolio almost surely in the long run.
$^{\dagger \dagger}$ It might seem strange that there is an optimal transport problem here, but the initial measure reflects an a priori belief about long-term market behavior, and the target measure represents the desired long-term portfolio distribution.

Perhap's the Sumio Watanabe's Innovative Approach to Complex Statistical Models

I’m not familiar with his work, but that would be a good answer to the question.

Link to some paper : https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.04537v1
